# Preciso fazer um SUM dentro do Group BY em Lambda

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda, nhibernate, hql

Estou tentando cria um relatório resumido onde consiste em fazer um `GROUP BY` com `SUM`, eu quero saber como eu poderia fazer isso em c# com lambda ou hql(Nhibernate), eu consegui fazer um GROUP BY, mas não consigo coloca o SUM,
um exemplo do que eu quero seria assim:

```
SELECT NumCarroId, 
      SUM(Litro) LitroTotal, 
      SUM(TotalGasto)TotalConsumido 
FROM Abastecimento 
GROUP BY NumCarroId
```

Porém como seria possivel fazer isso em HQL ou LINQ?

Comment: A resposta do Ricardo serve para sua pergunta?

Comment: Sim e não, queria saber como poem em Lambda para caso não consiga no LINQ, eu coloquei no código mas não tenho muito entendimento em LINQ

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta usando sintaxe de método, mas, no final das contas, o que muda se você usar uma sintaxe ou outra?

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam decidiu vim pro Entity? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O método **`GroupBy`** retorna uma estrutura de agrupamento.

Esta estrutura contém todos os dados do agrupamento em questão e também a chave (`Key`) dele — está chave é a responsável pelo agrupamento. Por exemplo, no seu caso, você quer agrupar os itens pela propriedade **`NumeroCarroId`** e, por isso, é esta propriedade que você passa como parâmetro para o método `GroupBy` e, consequemente, ela vira a chave (propriedade `Key`) desta estrutura de agrupamento que é retornada.

Então, você pode trabalhar em cima desta estrutura e usar o método `Count()` para retornar a quantidade de elementos de cada agrupamento, ou `Sum()` para somar os valores de alguma propriedade e assim por diante.

Vamos a um exemplo ilustrado, imagine que você tenha a seguinte estrutura na sua tabela

```
NumeroCarroId  | Litro  | TotalGasto
       1       |   10   |     50
       1       |   15   |     75
       2       |   10   |     50
       2       |   30   |     150
       2       |   05   |     25
```

Ao fazer isto

```
tabela.GroupBy(x => x.NumeroCarroId)
```

O resultado será uma estrutura assim

```
[
  {
    Key: 1, 
    _Items: [ 
      { NumeroCarroId: 1, Litro: 10, TotalGasto: 50 },
      { NumeroCarroId: 1, Litro: 15, TotalGasto: 75 } 
    ]
  }
  {
    Key: 2,
    _Items: [
      { NumeroCarroId: 2, Litro: 10, TotalGasto: 50 },
      { NumeroCarroId: 2, Litro: 30, TotalGasto: 150 },
      { NumeroCarroId: 2, Litro: 05, TotalGasto: 25 },
    ]
  }
}
```

<sup>Note que isto é uma mera ilustração simplificada para simular a estrutura retornada pelo método **`GroupBy`**.</sup>

Cada item desta estrutura é o `gp` no `Select` abaixo

```
tabela.GroupBy(x => x.NumeroCarroId)
      .Select(gp => new 
                    { 
                        NumeroCarroId = gp.Key,
                        LitroTotal = gp.Sum(c => c.Litro),
                        TotalConsumido = gp.Sum(c => c.TotalGasto)
                    });
```

A partir dela, você pode usar o método `ToList` para obter todos os itens dela, o método `Sum` para somar uma determinada propriedade, o método `Count` para contar os itens de cada agrupamento e algumas outras coisas.

O código, usando a sintaxe de método (o que você está chamando de lambda) ficaria assim:

```
var resultado = consulta.GroupBy(c => c.NumCarroId)
                        .Select(gp => new 
                                      { 
                                          NumeroCarroId = gp.Key,
                                          LitroTotal = gp.Sum(c => c.Litro),
                                          TotalConsumido = gp.Sum(c => c.TotalGasto)
                                      });
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73364/discussion-on-answer-by-linq-preciso-fazer-um-sum-dentro-do-group-by-em-lambda)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar LINQ para fazer o *group by* assim:

```
var resultado = from x in suaLista
                group x by NumCarroId into g
                select new 
                {
                        NumeroCarroId = g.NumCarroId,
                        LitroTotal = g.Sum(a => a.Litro),
                        TotalConsumido = g.Sum(b => b.TotalGasto)
                };
```

Onde **`suaLista`** é o seu objeto com o resultado que você quer agrupar, da tabela **`Abastecimento`**